# Binary read function doesn't work

Tags: c

I am new here and i need help for my homework. I have this binary file reader function which has been working very well until I changed a variable type in the a structure. So the variable was an `int`, and now it's a char[n] string in the `geptipus` structure.
And now the code freezes.

Here is the code :

```
typedef struct planetype
{
    char t[10 + 1];
    struct planetype next;
}planeytype;

typedef struct planedata
{
    char name[60 + 1];
    char nation[4 + 1];
    int speed;
    int max_altitude;
    int takeoff_run;
    int weight;
    int max_bomb_weight;
    int max_ammo_count;
    double caliber;

    struct planetype* tp;
    struct planedata* next;

} planedata;

void new_type(planedata *akt, char* value) //pipa
{

    planetype* type = (planetype*)malloc(sizeof(planetype));
    strcpy(type->t, value);
    type->next = akt->tp;
    akt->tp = type;
    //printf("%s", value);
}
void bin_read(planedata*head)
{
    int IsEnd = 0;
    char ch = '\0';
    char tempname[40 + 1];
    FILE *f1;
    int n;
    int i;
    char *k;
    planedata* data = head->next;
    f1 = fopen("type.dat", "rb");
    while (!IsEnd)
    {
        n = 0;
        while (ch != ' ' && IsEnd != 1)
        {
            fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, f1);
            if (ch == '\n')
            {
                IsEnd = 1;
            }
            if (ch != '\n')
            {
                tempname[n] = ch;
                    printf("%c", ch);
                n++;
            }
        }
        if (IsEnd != 1)
        {
            tempname[n - 1] = '\0';
            printf("%s ", tempname);
            data = PlaneName(head, tempname);
            for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                fread(&k, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
                    printf("%s", k);
                new_type(data, k);
            }
        }
        fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);
}
```

The program dies when the debugger reaches the `new_type` function and the `strcpy` line.

Comment: `char t[10 + 1];
    struct planetype next;` --> `char t[10 + 1];
    struct planetype *next;`

Comment: Why are you reading an `int` into a `char *`? Using `&k` (which is of type `char **`) causes `fread` to write somewhere where it shouldn't. How do you *write* the file? What is the data stored in the file there? What is the format of the file?

Comment: `char []` is an array, not a string.

Comment: The function was used in a different program which used an int type.

Comment: If the data is an `int`, then read into an `int`?

Comment: The file format is txt and its look like : "Name Type" in every line. The binary writing function runs perfectly

Comment: in the planetype structure the char t[10+1] was an int, but its not the task. that int was a way different task but similar structure

Comment: BLUEPIXY : it was my mistake when i translated the variables into english :D In the original code its not missing

Comment: could you just include the chunk of code that calls the function `void bin_read(planedata*head)`? Mainly to test your code properly

Comment: planedata* head = (planedata*)malloc(sizeof(planedata));head->next = read();bin_read(head);

Comment: The k pointer is the problem in this code. I call it with the char *value parameter and when i reach the line with the strcpy function the program dies with memory error. And i have no idea what is the problem

Comment: http://kepkezelo.com/images/iuzfntmb5b23a3w02e35.png This is the program while working. It reads the first word well, but it dies when it reaches the new_type function

Comment: Please post compilable code; what you've shown clearly won't compile.  Please post an MCVE ([MCVE]).  If you had previously working code that no longer works because you changed some things, you should go back to the version that worked.  You are using a version control system, aren't you?  If not, now is a few hours too late to start, but better late than never.  When things work, or even work more or less rather than fully, it is time to save the code so you can get back to that working code if (when?) you make mistakes.